# Bluetooth Dongle not working

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, debian-stretch, bluez

I buy a new LogiLink BT0015 USB Bluetooth dongle and want to install it on my Debian 9 system. After the installation process (bluetooth, bluez, blueman package), the dongle not working and the device will not be shown.

Hardware:

- Orange PI PC 2

Software:

- Debian Stretch

Kernel:

- Linux version 3.10.65 (orange@orange-All-Series) (gcc version 4.9.3 20150113 (prerelease) (Linaro GCC 4.9-2015.01-3) ) #55 SMP PREEMPT

**Output of dmesg -l err**

```
[    4.512939] Warning: can not find np for pmic0.
[    4.512983] Warning: can not find np for pmic1.
[    4.513071] add_sys_pwr_dm: get ldo name  for id: vcc-lpddr failed
[    4.513091] add_sys_pwr_dm: get ldo name  for id: vcc-pl failed
[    4.513109] add_sys_pwr_dm: axpdummy_ldo6 ldo already alwayson.
[    4.513141] add_sys_pwr_dm: vcc-pc not sys id.
[    4.513187] Warning: can not find np for dynamic_standby_para.
[    4.670401] sunxi_bootup_extend_probe: bootup extend state 1
[    4.670421] bootup extend probe ok
[    4.670978] failed to get easy_light_used assign
[    4.670996] failed to get standby led pin assign
[    5.614787] Get boot type cmd line fail
[    6.241953] hci: request ohci0-controller gpio:354
[    7.438870] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.sdmmc: smc 0 p0 err, cmd 52, RTO !!
[    7.446360] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.sdmmc: smc 0 p0 err, cmd 52, RTO !!
[    7.501222] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.sdmmc: smc 0 p0 err, cmd 5, RTO !!
[    7.502040] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.sdmmc: smc 0 p0 err, cmd 5, RTO !!
[    7.502856] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.sdmmc: smc 0 p0 err, cmd 5, RTO !!
[    7.503671] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.sdmmc: smc 0 p0 err, cmd 5, RTO !!
[    7.589050] AUDIO :get regulator name failed .
[    7.995323] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    7.995327] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.023979] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    8.023984] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.349935] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    8.355754] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.884609] EXT2-fs (mmcblk0p2): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    8.898683] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[   11.476575] [VFE_ERR]vfe sensor register check error at input_num = 0
[   12.538082] node ir_addr_code16 get failed!
[   12.543067] sunxi_ir_startup: cir get supply err
```

**Output of the syslog**

```
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 bluetoothd[7124]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 bluetoothd[7124]: Starting SDP server
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 bluetoothd[7124]: Bluetooth management interface 1.3 initialized
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 dbus[2146]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 NetworkManager[2154]: <info>  [1547051356.3753] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 dbus[2146]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan  9 17:29:16 devserver1 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
```

**Complete blueman syslog**

```
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 bluetoothd[3078]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez'
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 bluetoothd[3078]: Starting SDP server
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 bluetoothd[3078]: Bluetooth management interface 1.3 initialized
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 NetworkManager[2172]: <info>  [1547210791.9408] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Jan 11 13:46:31 devserver1 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 dbus-daemon[2876]: Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez.obex' unit='obex.service'
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 systemd[2851]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 obexd[3101]: OBEX daemon 5.43
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 dbus-daemon[2876]: Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'
Jan 11 13:46:32 devserver1 systemd[2851]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 org.blueman.Mechanism[2157]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 org.blueman.Mechanism[2157]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 blueman-mechani[3100]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Jan 11 13:46:33 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jan 11 13:47:03 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jan 11 13:47:27 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 org.blueman.Mechanism[2157]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 org.blueman.Mechanism[2157]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 dbus[2157]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 blueman-mechani[3272]: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Jan 11 13:47:28 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.868618] task: ffffffc01ac04380 ti: ffffffc012c98000 task.ti: ffffffc012c98000
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.876848] PC is at 0x7f98312784
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.880684] LR is at 0x7f94745484
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.884344] pc : [<0000007f98312784>] lr : [<0000007f94745484>] pstate: 60000000
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.892615] sp : 0000007fdda3eb20
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.896236] x29: 0000007fdda3eb30 x28: 0000007f958812f0
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.902193] x27: 0000007fdda3f0d0 x26: 0000005581f301d0
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.908009] x25: 0000000000000002 x24: 0000000000001000
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.914040] x23: 00000000000001c0 x22: 0000000000000001
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.919861] x21: 0000007f9477a000 x20: 000000558251c588
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.925978] x19: 0000000004000000 x18: 0000000000000000
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.931921] x17: 0000007f98312760 x16: 0000007f9477a348
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.937731] x15: 00000000000000b9 x14: ffffffffffffffe0
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.943749] x13: 0000000000000000 x12: 0000000000000000
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.949558] x11: 0101010101010101 x10: 0000007fdda3ea10
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.955661] x9 : 0000000000000001 x8 : 0000000000000117
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.961640] x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : 0000000000000000
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.967451] x5 : 0000007fdda3ea3c x4 : 0000007f98529108
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.973479] x3 : 0000007f98529000 x2 : 0000000000000002
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.979636] x1 : 0000000000000002 x0 : 0000007f94757730
Jan 11 13:47:43 devserver1 kernel: [  156.985446]
Jan 11 13:47:58 devserver1 blueman-mechanism: Exiting
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.102269] blueman-manager[3726]: syscall 279
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.107203] Code: aa0503e4 aa0603e5 aa0703e6 d4000001 (b13ffc1f)
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.113939] CPU: 3 PID: 3726 Comm: blueman-manager Not tainted 3.10.65 #55
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.121454] task: ffffffc03afe2440 ti: ffffffc028dc8000 task.ti: ffffffc028dc8000
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.129657] PC is at 0x7fac8a2784
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.133302] LR is at 0x7fa8cd5484
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.136920] pc : [<0000007fac8a2784>] lr : [<0000007fa8cd5484>] pstate: 60000000
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.145079] sp : 0000007fe2c70810
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.148702] x29: 0000007fe2c70820 x28: 0000007fa9e11270
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.154558] x27: 0000007fe2c70dc0 x26: 000000557d31e1d0
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.160365] x25: 0000000000000002 x24: 0000000000001000
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.166928] x23: 00000000000001c0 x22: 0000000000000001
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.172801] x21: 0000007fa8d0a000 x20: 000000557d9aef38
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.178609] x19: 0000000004000000 x18: 0000000000000000
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.184439] x17: 0000007fac8a2760 x16: 0000007fa8d0a348
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.190246] x15: 00000000000000b9 x14: ffffffffffffffe0
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.196074] x13: 0000000000000000 x12: 0000000000000000
Jan 11 13:49:13 devserver1 kernel: [  246.201971] x11: 0101010101010101 x10: 0000007fe2c70700
Jan 11 13:49:14 devserver1 kernel: [  246.207779] x9 : 0000000000000001 x8 : 0000000000000117
Jan 11 13:49:14 devserver1 kernel: [  246.213607] x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : 0000000000000000
Jan 11 13:49:14 devserver1 kernel: [  246.219414] x5 : 0000007fe2c7072c x4 : 0000007facab9108
Jan 11 13:49:14 devserver1 kernel: [  246.225242] x3 : 0000007facab9000 x2 : 0000000000000002
Jan 11 13:49:14 devserver1 kernel: [  246.231085] x1 : 0000000000000002 x0 : 0000007fa8ce7730
Jan 11 13:49:14 devserver1 kernel: [  246.236896]
```

**blueman-manager log**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLdAk.jpg)

**blueman-adapers log**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ93Q.jpg)

Have anyone an idea, to fix the problem?

Comment: Anything in dmesg & syslog after plugging / unplugging it?

Comment: Which kernel version are you using?

Comment: @TDK I used kernel number 3.10.65.

Comment: provide output of: sudo dmesg -l err

Comment: @AtomiX84 I updated the first post.

Comment: @Xen2050 I see inside dmesg the normal log of the package installation process. You find the output of the syslog in the main post.

Comment: Hmm, don't see any failure messages... exactly what happens when you try running the bluetooth programs? without adapters my `blueman-manager` says *"Connection to BlueZ failed - Bluez daemon is not running ... probably means there were no Bluetooth adapters"*. Or `blueman-adapters` sends messages to syslog (but nothing to dmesg) like: *"dbus[4845]: [system] Activated service 'org.bluez' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1 "*. And have you tested the device on another computer, is it 100% working?

Comment: @Xen2050 I tested the device on a windows pc and it works perfectly. The starting process looks like a normal blueman starting process. But there were no available adapters. I updated the main post and load pictures of the log for the blueman-manager and blueman-adapters command. I also posted the complete (kernel, blueman) log of the syslog file. It's a complete log of the blueman starting process. I also can`t connect (console) the adapter with the system.

Comment: Can anyone check my logs? If there any problem?